# lightswitch Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

i have a lightswitch application which contains the following table structure

Item (A)
----Store (B)
--------Store Contact (C)

each store have many store contact.

when i add a new row of Store Contact (C) and try to save it locally (on my PC) it gets saved, but when i publish the application and try to add new Store Contact (C) and save it it will give the following error:

[image]

however if i tried to edit an existed Store Contact (C) and save the changes it will get saved (locally and on the server).

Any solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

the `Store Contact (C)` contains a type filed (phone,email,etc..) which had some non-English letters.

i don't know why this issue occurred on the server and not on my pc.